# PL/SQl Error. Can't figure it out

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have tried to execute code the instruction below. But somehow I cant get it working. I am new to PL/SQl. Any hint will be valuable thanks

The rank table has:

```
rankID   Number
name     Varchar2(255 BYTE)
```

/*
Write PL/SQL program (anonymous block) that prints out a list of all ranks (ID 
and name) for all rank ID from 100 to 110. If a rank ID (xxx) does not appear 
in the rank table the program should print out: NO RANK AVAILABLE for ID: 
xxx

*/

```
--set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    rank_id NUMBER;
    rank_name VARCHAR2(255);
    loopcount NUMBER;
BEGIN
    loopcount :=100;
    FOR k IN 100..110 
    LOOP
        SELECT rankID, name
        INTO rank_id, rank_name
        FROM rank
        WHERE rankID=loopcount;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rank_id||'     '|| rank_name); 
            loopcount := loopcount + 1;
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO RANK AVAILABLE for ID: '||rank_id);
END;
/
```

Below is what I am getting. Its not working the way it should

```
Server output:
100     Chefpilot
NO RANK AVAILABLE for ID: 100

DECLARE executed successfully

Execution time: 0.26s
```

Comment: In the rank table, there are only three columns with rankID, which are 100, 105, and 110. My codes should print out these three rows containing 100, 105, 110 rankID and their corresponding names, but my code just prints only for 100 and also print exceptions as well. I will update my error shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sgeddes's approach is better, but to explain what you are seeing, if you did want to use your mechamism then you'd need to catch the exception in an inner block. At the moment the exception handler is outside the loop, so the first error you see terminates the loop. With an inner block:

```
DECLARE
    rank_id NUMBER;
    rank_name VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    FOR loopID IN 100..110 
    LOOP
        BEGIN -- inner block
            SELECT rankID, name
            INTO rank_id, rank_name
            FROM rank
            WHERE rankID=loopID;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rank_id||'     '|| rank_name); 
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO RANK AVAILABLE for ID: '||loopID);
        END; -- inner block
    END LOOP;   
END;
/
```

Now if the ID doesn't exist the exception is caught, the message is printed, and the inner block exits; which means the loop continues at the next iteration. (I've also removed the extra `loopcount` and consistently used a `loopID` for the `for` and both references).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

No real need for a loop in this case, you can do this with an `outer join`, a `case` statement and a numbers table:

```
WITH CTE (RankId) AS (
  SELECT 100 RankId
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT RankId + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE RankId < 110
) 
SELECT t.RankId, COALESCE(r.Name, 'Does not exist') Name,
  CASE 
    WHEN r.RankId IS NULL THEN 'No rank available for: ' || t.RankId 
    ELSE r.RankId || ' ' || r.Name
  END Description
FROM CTE t
  LEFT JOIN rank r ON t.RankId = r.RankId 
ORDER BY t.RankId
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12e4c3/4)